# Progress Bar with partial, unsequential areas of fill - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios6

I need to make a kind of progress bar for the reading levels of a book.

When the user reads the certain pages of the book, the progress bar should show the visual progress that highlights only specific area of the progress bar for the pages that have been read.

For example, if the total number of pages for a book is 100 and user has read the page 1 to 10 and 90 to 100, the bar should show the 10% highlight on the extreme left and 10% highlight on the extreme right. This way, the progress bar will show different areas in it that have been read.

I can't seem to find the native methods in the UIProgress bar that supports this. Is there anyway this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

for that you have to create custom progressbar you can use core graphics and and fill area of uiview corresponding to progress

divide total number of pages by width of uiview and use that.

use that link for know about core graphics [Core Graphics Draw lines , rectangles](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients)

Comment: Could you please lead me to the logic that can be implemented for this? Drawing the filled rects, that is.